# Got Error on updating status picklist value for campaign object using import wizard

Tags: data-import-wizard

when i am updating status picklist field using import wizard i got this Error

> The status field is not mapped and is required for an update operation

please let me know, urgently please provide solution?

Answer (score 1):

This error would normally suggest you have not mapped the field during the mapping stage of the wizard.
The status field on Lead is a required field.

Does this help. If not please post more detail like screen shots of the wizard stages and error